# Parse string with offset to Instant Java 11

Tags: java, java.time.instant

I am trying to parse the following string `2021-10-15T08:39:05+02:00` into an `Instant` this works seamlessly using Java 15 but throws an error for Java 11.

`java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-10-19T11:06:35+02:00' could not be parsed at index 19`

Why is that the case?

```
Instant.parse("2021-10-15T08:39:05+02:00");
```

Edit: Java 15

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Instant.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) says:

> The string ... is parsed using `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`.

So, read the docs for `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`:

- [Java 15](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT)

  > When parsing, the behaviour of `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendOffsetId()` will be used to parse the offset, converting the instant to UTC as necessary
- [Java 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT)

  > When parsing ... (nothing about how the offset is parsed)

The behavior has changed between the two to make `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT` (and code making using of it) accept a broader range of inputs.

To get an `Instant` from that string with Java 11, you can first parse to a [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)), then use `toInstant()` to get the corresponding `Instant`.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT), used internally by the `java.time.Instant#parse`, behavior have changed to support the timezone offset when parsing an instant.

You can achieve the same behavior that will work seamlessly across different *Java* versions starting from *1.8* onward using the [`java.time.OffsetDateTime#parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) chained with [`java.time.OffsetDateTime#toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toInstant()):

```
Instant i = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-10-15T08:39:05+02:00").toInstant();
```